# button does not click inside listview adatper

Tags: android, listview

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aT4fBwjJrIgkfpLJoxxmK1mC-5RY3_aQ/view?usp=sharing) is a picture of my layout. I want to be able to click on the play button on the left hand side. I am current only able to click on the button on the last row. I tried to click on the other rows but only the last row would respond to the click. Following is my source codes:

custom_list_item_layout:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_view_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/play_pause_id"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/task_view_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"

                />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/play_pause_id"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/play_btn"

                />

        </RelativeLayout>



        </RelativeLayout>
```

Custom list adapter class:

```
        package com.example.study.studytimer;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.List;

    public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task>{
        Context mCtx;
        int resource;
        List<Task> taskList;
        ImageButton playSelect;
        private boolean isPressed = false;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context mCtx, int resource, List<Task> taskList) {
            super(mCtx, resource, taskList);
            this.mCtx = mCtx;
            this.resource = resource;
            this.taskList = taskList;

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx);


            View view = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            TextView tvTask = view.findViewById(R.id.task_view_id);
            TextView tvHour = view.findViewById(R.id.time_view_id);
            playSelect = view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_id);


            playSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    isPressed = !isPressed;
                    if (isPressed) {
                        playSelect.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_btn);
                    } else {
                        playSelect.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_btn);
                    }
                }
            });

            Task task = taskList.get(position);
            Log.d("getViewCustomList", "getView: " + task.getTask_name());
            tvTask.setText(task.getTask_name());
            tvHour.setText(task.getNum_hours());

            return view;
        }

    }
```

Comment: isPressed = !isPressed; your isPressed is always false Please try to add a simple Toast and check it

Comment: that part works because it switches between two different drawables.

Comment: add a toast and check in every click it showing or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to define `playSelect` inside the `getView` method for each item.

```
            ImageButton playSelect = view.findViewById(R.id.play_pause_id);
```

each item must has its listener with a defferent objecct.

Comment: Glad to hear that

Answer (score 0):

Use 'v' reference instead of 'playSelect' reference to change the drawable.

```
if (isPressed) {
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause_btn);
} else {
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.play_btn);
}
```

You also need to store value of isPressed with each item entry. You can set tag on button or you can create arraylist to store the value.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code it works fine. all rows are responding to the click the but only problem i found that you have decalred isPressed as global variable you should have used final one element array as local variable with each item for it to work properly. if this is not what you are looking please write in comments.you can check following example:

```
 final boolean[] isPressed = {false};
        playSelect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isPressed[0] = !isPressed[0];
                if (isPressed[0]) {
                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mCtx, "Not Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Replace `Toast` with your action.